# How to navigate from fragment to fragment within active tab

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, navigation, android-navigation

I am new to using the navigation component for Android. Most of the examples I have seen online discuss fragment navigation within an activity but, in my case, I want to navigate within a base fragment. In the picture below, I would like to navigate from a login fragment to a signup fragment within the same settings tab but am running into issues and have tried various possible solutions. Any help would be appreciated as I am aware that I can certainly missing something.

```html
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation action/destination com.example.animaljournalapp:id/action_userAccountFragment_to_userSignUpFragment cannot be found from the current destination Destination(com.example.animaljournalapp:id/navigation_settings) label=Settings class=com.example.animaljournalapp.ui.settings.UserAccountFragment
```

[image]

I attempt to perform the navigation in the login fragment file through a listener I have attached to a "Sign Up" button:

UserAccountFragment.kt

```html
class UserAccountFragment : Fragment() {


    private lateinit var userAccountModel: UserAccountModel

    private lateinit var navHostFrag: Fragment

private var _binding: FragmentUserAccountBinding? = null
  // This property is only valid between onCreateView and
  // onDestroyView.
  private val binding get() = _binding!!

  override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
  ): View? {
    userAccountModel =
            ViewModelProvider(this).get(UserAccountModel::class.java)

      navHostFrag = SettingsMainFragment()

    _binding = FragmentUserAccountBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    val root: View = binding.root

      val loginButton: Button = root.findViewById(R.id.login_button)

      val signupButton: Button = root.findViewById(R.id.signup_button)


      loginButton.setOnClickListener{ view: View ->
          Toast.makeText(this.context, "Hi", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
      }

      signupButton.setOnClickListener { view: View ->
          val action = UserAccountFragmentDirections.actionUserAccountFragmentToUserSignUpFragment()
          Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(action)
      }

    return root
  }

override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

The main activity has a navigation graph of the following:

mobile_navigation.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/navigation_home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:name="com.example.animaljournalapp.ui.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
        android:name="com.example.animaljournalapp.ui.dashboard.DashboardFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_dashboard"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_dashboard" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_settings"
        android:name="com.example.animaljournalapp.ui.settings.UserAccountFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_settings"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_settings_main" />
</navigation>
```

settings_navigation.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/settings_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/userAccountFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/userAccountFragment"
        android:name="com.example.animaljournalapp.ui.settings.UserAccountFragment"
        android:label="fragment_user_account"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_user_account" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_userAccountFragment_to_userSignUpFragment"
            app:destination="@id/userSignUpFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/userSignUpFragment"
        android:name="com.example.animaljournalapp.ui.settings.UserSignUpFragment"
        android:label="UserSignUpFragment" />
</navigation>
```

fragment_settings_main.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.settings.SettingsMainFragment">


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/settings_nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/settings_navigation" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: There's a reason the docs don't nest one NavHostFragment inside another - it is basically always the wrong way to do it (here, you have a `android:id="@+id/navigation_settings"` in your main navigation graph that loads `UserAccountFragment`, but also have a separate `android:id="@+id/userAccountFragment"` inside your settings navigation graph that also loads `UserAccountFragment`??). I don't think you need any of this weird structure at all. Please explain what exactly you are trying to do. Navigating to another fragment is just calling 'navigate', no nested hosts needed.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I was hoping to do some nested navigation basically. In this case, move from fragment A to fragment B while staying in the same active tab. (e.g. does not make sense to go to a "edit profile" page while on the home tab but rather makes sense to do so while on the settings tab)